# How to merge objects and append it into new array if object values are same using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of data,  my goal is to find all same `request_id` values in the given objects, merge it to one object and append its `unique_id` into one array, How can I get this result?

```js
let fakeData = {
    "622b1e4a8c73d4742a66434e212":{
      request_id: "1",
      uique_id:'001'
    },
    "622b1e4a8c73d4742a6643423e54":{
        request_id: "1",
        uique_id:'002'
    },
    "622b1e4a8c73d4742a6643423e23":{
        request_id: "2",
        uique_id:'003'
    },
  }

  let parts = []

  for (const property in fakeData) {
      console.log(fakeData[property]);
  }


  //Result should be
  // [{request_id:'1', values:["001, 002"]}, {request_id:'2', values:["003"]}]
```

Comment: Start by trying to see if  you can build a new object that has the `request_id` values as keys, and an array as property that houses all entries with that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all the values using `Object.values()` and `array#reduce`. In the `array#reduce` group based on `request_id` in an object and extract all the values of these object using `Object.values()`.

```js
const fakeData = { "622b1e4a8c73d4742a66434e212": { request_id: "1", uique_id: '001' }, "622b1e4a8c73d4742a6643423e54": { request_id: "1", uique_id: '002' }, "622b1e4a8c73d4742a6643423e23": { request_id: "2", uique_id: '003' }, },
      output = Object.values(fakeData).reduce((r, {request_id, uique_id}) => {
        r[request_id] ??= {request_id, values: []};
        r[request_id].values.push(uique_id);
        return r;
      },{}),
      result = Object.values(output);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```